# toLocaleDateString returns unexpected formatted time

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

The below call returns `24:00` in latest Chrome & Opera, while it previously returned `00:00`, is this a by design behavior?

```js
const [, time] = new Date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-us",
        {
            hour12: false,
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }).split(", ");

console.info(time); // 24:00
```

Comment: What happens if you specify `”en-GB”` (which uses 24-hour clock natively) instead of `”en-US”`? I suspect it’s related to how 12-hour clocks (which en-US use by default) never show “00:00” for midnight use show “12:00” instead - so maybe there’s a setting for “don’t show all-zeroes”?

Comment: @Dai that fixed it

Comment: @Dai you can just put it in console and test right away

Comment: @Huangism I’m writing these comments on my iPad in bed at 6:38am :) - I don’t have access to a JS console.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using `toLocaleDateString` to format a time? Wouldn't it make more sense to use [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString)?

Comment: @Heteric - I'm doing more than just time formatting, that's why, this is irrelevant for the purpose of this question

Comment: what's interesting is does 24:00 represent a valid time in any of the cultures?

Comment: GB returns day/month btw, incase you are trying to parse the date, but yea never seen 24:00 anywhere

Comment: @Huangism - I'm aware of that, I need the US formatting anyway, point is it used to work recently.

Comment: @user1514042 chrome gets updated all the time, only if there is an easy way to ask them

Comment: @Huangism - I can see a lot of issues raised specifically around toLocaleDateString - should this call be considered as tricky and avoided for cross-browser dev?

Comment: Fair enough. Just wondering about "right tool for the job" kind of thing. I'd probably use `Intl.DateTimeFormat`'s [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) myself, then you have full control over which parts you want to keep, and which you want to throw away. BTW, [ECMAScript says that if the hour is 0, and the hour cycle is defined as 24 hours, make hour `24` (step 14.c.vi.)](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#sec-partitiondatetimepattern).

Comment: @user1514042 I don't know enough about it to give you a good answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like Chrome (or its V8 engine) has updated to match [the specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/#sec-partitiondatetimepattern), which says in Step 18(e)(vi):

> If *p* is "hour" and dateTimeFormat.[[HourCycle]] is "h24", then
>   If *v* is 0, let v be 24.

That specification hasn't changed, but it looks like they must have fixed a bug. (I didn't immediately find one in the V8 or Chromium issue list, but...)

Interestingly, Firefox shows `00:00`, not `24:00`.

Comment: Not sure about the logic driving that fix, but '24:35' as time does look confusing.

Answer (score 8):

Use `hourCycle` instead of `hour12` and set it to `h23`.

```js
const [, time] = new Date(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0).toLocaleDateString("en-us",
        {
            hourCycle: "h23",
            hour: "2-digit",
            minute: "2-digit"
        }).split(", ");

console.info(time); // 00:00
```